# restoring .gz backup file in postgresql 9.1 installed on windows 7 32bit os

Tags: postgresql, database-restore, gzip

I have a database backup file in .gz format.I need to restore it in postgresql 9.1 which is installed on windows 7 32bit os.The problem is postgresql does not support the backup file in gz format,so I cannot restore it.If anybody knows a solution please post your answer...

Answer (score 4):

.gz isn't a backup format, it just means the file has been compressed with gzip. A copy of winzip or 7-zip should be able to decompress it. Then you'll either have a 'custom' format backup which can be restored with pg_restore or raw sql which can be run through psql.

You can also use pgadmin instead of the above tools. See the manuals for more details.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/reference-client.html

Comment: If you aren't sure what kind of backup it is, just try to restore it with `pg_restore` or with PgAdmin-III's restore function. Unfortunately `pg_restore` doesn't understand plain SQL format dumps, so if it fails try `psql -f backup-file target-database` after decompressing the file.